# Prevent Select-Xml from converting special characters

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML file containing some special characters in a field like so:

```
<elem>
 <inelem>..</inelem>
 <inelem>&#13;</inelem>
</elem>
```

I am editing with powershell code:

```
$xml = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xml.Load($file)
$xml.elem.inelem.InnerText = "..."
$xml.Save($file)
```

The output has the special character in the last field converted, is there a way to prevent the conversion?